# What is the best and easiest way of generating SEO friendly urls with ASP.NET 3.5

Tags: asp.net, seo

What is the best and easiest way of generating SEO friendly urls with ASP.NET 3.5. I saw url rewriter but i don't think it is good enough for me. Thank you for your all answers.

Comment: More information please - can you provide some examples of the kind of URLs you're working with, and what SEO friendly URLs you're trying to generate?
Also, what wasn't 'good enough' about URL Rewriter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way for SEO friendly urls is using System.Web.Routing

Detailed information : http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&biw=1920&bih=760&q=System.Web.Routing&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=

How to use example :

At Global.asax file

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes);
}


    void RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute(
       "pokedex",
       "MonsterDex",
       "~/MonsterDex.aspx"
    );
}
```

Live example : http://www.monstermmorpg.com/MonsterDex

Comment: but that is `ASP.Net 4.0` not `ASP.Net 3.5`

Comment: incorrect : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx Configuring ASP.NET for Routing
To configure an ASP.NET Web site or Web application for routing, you first need to add a reference to the System.Web.Routing assembly. The SP1 installation for the .NET Framework 3.5 will install this assembly into the global assembly cache, and you can find the assembly inside the standard "Add Reference" dialog box.

Comment: here version 3.5 : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: sorry but [System.Web.Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.aspx) states that is a `.Net framework 4.0`

Comment: i see your point now :) well he can convert 4.0 or use this way public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1840/discussion-between-miroprocessor-and-pokemoncraft)

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Url Rewrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx). you can check [Tip/Trick: Url Rewriting with ASP.NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx) and [URL Rewriting with ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/urlrewriter.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Long long time ago I seen: http://www.asp.net/mvc